What is the numerical error of the signal.iirdesign methods in scipy?
How large are the numerical errors of the signal.iirdesign method from SciPy?
I am trying to implement a digital filter on an FPGA, but at low frequencies, the filter is often unstable. I am not sure if the precision errors come from the generated coefficients or the hardware implementation, although I am leaning towards the former since the bit widths of the internal signals in the FPGA are very large (24 bit signed). For generating the coefficients, I mostly used the Chebyshev II method. The filter is a fourth order SOS filter with a sampling rate of roughly 2 kHz.
As an example, I tried a 17 Hz to 180 Hz bandpass filter, which worked, but when I lowered the lower cutoff to 8 Hz, the filter became unstable.
Example code:
sos = signal.cheby2(4, Wn = [8, 180], rs=20, btype = "bandpass", analog = False, output='sos', fs=2000)

yields the coefficients (24 in total):
[[ 0.08881972 -0.05383479  0.08881972  1.         -1.14507803  0.37643573]
 [ 1.         -1.64403822  1.          1.         -1.61981503  0.81546484]
 [ 1.         -1.99990031  1.          1.         -1.96083347  0.96140331]
 [ 1.         -1.99945422  1.          1.         -1.9853932   0.98632281]]

I think the three coefficients 1., -1.99990031, and 1. completely annihilate the signal. For lowpass filters, I even often obtained 1., -2., and 1. Usually, the filter worked when the second coefficient was above -1.998 or so.
To simulate the precision errors in the hardware, I did this:
sos_scaled = sos*mult_factor
sos_quantized = np.round(sos_scaled).astype(int)

z, p, k = signal.sos2zpk(sos_quantized / mult_factor)
poles = np.abs(p)

In my implementation, mult_factor is 2^21. For all filters I tested I made sure that the (quantised) poles are within the unit circle.
To plot the frequency response using the quantised coefficients, I used:
w, h = signal.sosfreqz(sos_quantized / mult_factor, worN=8000)

The filter has transposed direct form II:

In the box labeled Q(z), the internal signals are quantised to the bit width of the input/output signal (14 bit signed).

24 bit accumulator precision is likely the root cause of the instability and insufficient to implement a filter with a very high ratio of sampling rate to bandwidth. To answer the OP's question: The scipy tools using double-precision floating point will allow simulation up to 54 bits of equivalent fixed-point precision in the FPGA before limiting performance (although for FPGA modelling and simulation, I recommend Python bit and cycle accurate fixed-point simulations, not floating point: see the bottom of my post for further details on that).
Below are recommended options to resolve the instability (in addition to Hilmar's good suggestions):

Increase the accumulator precision, or

Change filter structure to one of the alternative implementations to the standard "Direct Form I" or "Transposed Direct Form II" 2nd order filter sections detailed below, or

Decimate to a lower rate so that the ratio of sampling rate to bandwidth is more manageable.



Alternative Implementations for High Sampling Rate to BW Ratio
Factoring higher order IIR filters into a cascade of Second-Order-Sections (SOS), also referred to as the "Biquad", is the typical first step (and "always do this" step) toward good stability and minimizing round-off noise. In addition to doing that and Hilmar's other good advice, the following is a summary of alternate forms for increased IIR precision of those SOS filters with poles that are very close to DC or Nyquist:

Rader and Gold Coupled Form
Agarwal and Burrus Form
Lattice Structure
fred harris: Rotate by j, filter, and rotate by -j
Noise Shaping

First to clarify the issue further when implementing such filters with poles near $z=\pm 1$ (DC or Nyquist), the graphic below shows the distribution of possible roots when the coefficients in the Biquad filter are quantized. What we see here specifically is the non-uniform distribution with greater error as we approach roots that are desired to be placed near $z=1$. Poles contribute gain amplification to filters, and the closer a pole is to the unit circle the more dominant it is in the response, hence our greatest concern here is the larger error in vicinity of $z=1$. Please see DSP.SE #85937 for further details on what this graphic is showing and the related issue with such filter implementations:

I'll detail or reference further info for each below:
Rader and Gold Coupled Form
See: C.M. Rader and B. Gold, “Effects of parameter quantization on the poles of a digital filter,” Proc. IEEE, vol 55, pp 685-689, May 1967, also see
Rick Lyons, “Coupled-Form 2nd Order IIR Resonators: A Contradiction Resolved, https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/183.php
In summary the standard implementation for the poles in a Biquad SOS are shown below as the "Direct Form 2nd Order Resonator". The Rader and Gold Coupled Form as an alternate implementation of the same is shown on the right. At the cost of doubling the number of multipliers needed, the quantization of the poles will be uniform across the z-plane, resulting in better accuracy and lower quantization noise for the cases when the poles are in vicinity of $z=\pm1$ (DC and Nyquist).

Agarwal-Burrus
See Ramesh C. Agarwal and C. Sidney Burrus, "New Recursive Digital Filter Structures Having Very Low Sensitivity and Roundoff Noise",  IEEE Trans. On Circuits and Systems, Vol/ CAS=22. No 12, Dec 1975.
and:
Agarwal and Burrus, "Low noise realizations for narrow-band recursive digital filters," IEEE x-actions on Acoustics, Speech and Signal Processing, Feb 1980
What I will note here with the Agarwal and Burrus forms is the "Agarwal-Burrus Realization 2" where the point $z=1$ on the z-plane is moved to the origin with the mapping $\hat{z}=z-1$. Such a mapping results in replacing unit delays with delaying accumulators:
$$\hat{z} = z-1$$
So
$$\hat{z}^{-1} = \frac{1}{z-1} = \frac{z^{-1}}{1-z^{-1}}$$
The final form expressed with negative powers of $z$ makes it easy to see the implementation, given $z^{-1}$ is (the z-transform of) a time delay of one sample:

This is useful for fixed point implementations with poles near $z=1$ since it replaces large coefficients with small coefficients, which are more accurate to realize given the same word length.
The graphic below demonstrates the process by showing the implementation of a high-Q DC nulling filter, which has a pole very close to $z=1$ (the closer it is, the higher the Q, and the more challenging it is to implement!). The graphic on the left is the classical implementation, where the pole is set by the coefficient $\alpha$ (so typically a number close to but not greater than one). The structure shown in the middle is the same filter in the $\hat{z}$ plane, based on the mapping $\hat{z} = z-1$, so we basically shifted all poles and zeros to the left by subtracting 1 from them. This results in the block diagram (using $\hat{z}^{-1}$ blocks) shown in the middle graphic. We implement the $\hat{z}^{-1}$ block with an accumulator, resulting in the final implementation diagram shown on the right which will have a transfer function matching that of the original high-Q DC nulling filter.

Lattice
The lattice structure for an all-pole 2nd order filter implementation is shown below. It is my understanding that this form is less sensitive to round-off noise, but this is not something I have yet personally verified.

The transfer function from the input to the All-Pass output is given as $H_1(z)$ below:
$$H_1(z) = \frac{K_1+(K_2+K_1K_2)z^{-1}+z^{-2}}{1+(K_2+K_1K_2)z^{-1}+K_1z^{-2}}$$
The transfer function from the input to the All-Pole IIR output is given as $H_2(z)$ below:
$$H_1(z) = \frac{1}{1+(K_2+K_1K_2)z^{-1}+K_1z^{-2}}$$
fred harris: rotate by j, filter and rotate back
At the 2021 DSP Online Conference fred harris presented "The DSP Biquadratic Recursive Filter: A Fox in the Hen House" which included the Rader and Gold form and outlined the details of implementing an IIR filter by moving the roots to $f_s/4$, heterodyne the signal to $f_s/4$, then filter the heterodyned signal, and then heterodyne the signal back. Further this was elegantly done with resampling techniques such that quadrature processing wasn't necessary. There are a lot of other great details in this presentation regarding such filters with a large sampling rate to bandwidth ratio.
Noise Shaping
Robert Bristow-Johnson (RBJ) details in other posts here truncation error feedback techniques where the error from the truncation of a higher precision accumulator to the lower precision output is fed back into the accumulator on the next sample. Thus a zero is placed in the noise transfer function (round-off noise in the filter) at $z=1$ (DC), suppressing the noise from round-off at low frequencies. This is similar to noise shaping techniques used in Delta-Sigma converters. Please see these posts below that detail this technique further:
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/66280/21048
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/67944/21048
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/21800/21048

Filter Simulation
24 bits in the FPGA is about the same precision as single precision (32 bit) floating point which offers 25 bits for rounding noise considerations, but far inferior to the double precision, which the scipy tools will use by default, which offers 54 bits (Related to that, see my Puzzle Question DSP.SE #38832).
The precision effects on the IIR filter will both be coefficient quantization and round-off noise feeding back into the filter, amplifying the noise due to round-off. Quantizing the coefficients changes the achievable frequency response, which is straightforward to model as the OP has done with rounding or more typically truncation depending on the actual FPGA implementation. Evaluating the quantization effects on round-off noise is most expediently evaluated with a fixed-point model, but can be understood from the graphic below showing how for the case of a feed-back IIR system, each quantization noise source gets fed back into the accumulator over the lifetime of the feedback (as given by the impulse response, i.e. the memory of the filter) and thus can accumulate to potentially large values.

I highly recommend creating a bit and cycle accurate fixed-point model of the FPGA implementation as that will quickly determine the accumulator precision required to meet a precision requirement. The Python tools and models used for efficiently implementing Direct Form I and Transposed Direct Form II fixed-point Biquad filters are part of two online courses I teach with the first one starting next week June 13th, 2024! This course combines  pre-recorded video with live Q&A sessions with me at Europe/Asia and North America times. The graphics used in this post are from that course.
"DSP for Wireless Communications": provides Python filter models and fixed-point simulation tools for demonstration; this is a deep dive in filters/DSP but not a deep dive in Python. Next course starting June 13, 2024 through dsprelated.com/courses.
"Python Applications in Digital Design and Signal Processing": provides Python filter models and fixed-point simulation tools; this is a deep dive in Python from the ground-up including using for digital design simulation, but using DSP only as demonstration. Next course staring August 29, 2024 through ieeeboston.org/courses.

Fixed point IIR filters at low frequencies are VERY difficult to implement.
Some things that need to be carefully managed are

Implement only as cascaded second order section
Implement each section either as Direct Form or Transposed Form II. The other two options are numerically really bad
Pole zero pairing matters
Stage ordering matters
Stage gains/scaling needs to be carefully optimized for each stage in terms of clipping risk and signal to noise ratio. That typically requires making some assumption the properties of the input signal (distribution, spectrum, crest factor, etc.)
Coefficient quantization matters (but probably not in your case)

Without looking at your exact details it's hard to guess what might be going wrong: this often turns into a "layers of the onion" problem. Once you fix one issue you discover the next one underneath.

the bit widths of the internal signals in the FPGA are very large (24 bits signed)

24-bit is not exactly large. I've seen 32-bit floating point go sideways. It really depends on what your target SNR is.

Thanks a lot for your answer, that helped me a lot! Fortunately, I did use Transposed Direct Form II. However, I am actually not sure if I quantise at the right spot. Also, can you maybe please shortly elaborate on the stage ordering? Is it possible that the ordering returned by the iirdesign function is not optimal?

@Lenny: yes, it's definitely possible that the stage ordering isn't optimal. Optimizing stage gain and ordering is a tedious and complicated process that depends somewhat on the properties of your input signal. Transposed Form II should only have 2 delays. If you implement it as drawn, you are probably in trouble specifically with the right side path.  Do all the multipliers have 48 bits output? Are the delay states in 24-bit or 48 bit ?

Why do you think using 4 delays instead of 2 matters? I used 4 because I found it easier to implement in the hardware. The bit length of the output of the multipliers is just the sum of the bit widths of the inputs, so in my implementation that is 14 + 24 = 38 bit. Then, for adding the output of the multiplier to the value from the previous register, I use a 39 bit representation, but I cast this to 24 bit before saving it in the next register (so in system verilog, assign sum = num_of_bits_internal'(add_out);, where num_of_bits_internal is 24)

@Lenny: the delays matter very much.  It changes the definition of the state variables (now you have 4 instead of 2) and the transfer functions from the input to the states
